# How to test if there's a certain link on the returned page in Rails using Rspec and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm writing tests for a project and this is the first time I'm writing tests on Rails and I'm having a little trouble.
Here's the situation, after I click on Submit, on the page returned I should have a link called "View" with a certain url. So what I'm doing is this:

```
    it 'should be able to review' do
#submit review
      click_on 'Submit'

      #expect result
      expect(page).to have_link('View', href: "/response/view?a_id=#{@a.id}")
    end
```

And I'm sure that the link exists on the page because I tested this manually, and if I delete the line `expect(page)` the test will pass. Is there something wrong with what I wrote? Also, I tried `expect(page).to have_link('View')` and it does not work either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have to debug the test, with the Capybara instruction `save_and_open_page` so you can actually confirm what the page is rendering and what is happening.

For this you have to install the `launchy` gem

Here is a useful link: https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy#capybara-testing to set it up and see how it works

Comment: Thanks! Now I know the problem came from a failed link address I used to upload the form. Thank you. The method is working now.